# Back to My Mac - Can people see it?

Tags: time-capsule, airport, back-to-my-mac

I just enabled "Back to My Mac" so that I can access my Time Capsule when I'm out and about. I'm just curious if other people can see my Time Capsule in their "Shared" tab in Finder (or anywhere else), whether they are within vicinity of my Time Capsule or not (though it seems unlikely if they aren't near it...). I've only added my own iTunes account to Back to My Mac, but I just want to be sure.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Any device that is broadcasting radio signal (in this case the WiFi) can be seen by anyone in the vicinity of the signal range.

They do not see inside of it (your iTunes), just the name it is broadcasting.